# Jquery Onclick Send data to new opened window

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

I know this is a common question but I can't find any answer.
I have a PHP file which contains a link. When that link is clicked, I want to open another page in a new window, and on this newly opened page I want to get the ID attribute of the link clicked on the previous page.

> Current page= 'patientreg.php'
>   Newpage to open in new window= 'patient_history.php'
>   Post data from current page to new loaded page.

Current page Code:

**HTML:**

```
<a id="37" onclick="phistory(this.id);" href="#">View history</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function phistory(myVar) {  
    var myurl = '../main/patient_history.php';  
    $.post(myurl,{data:myVar},function(){});  
    window.open(myurl,'_blank');                
}
```

**New page code:**

```
$phid = $_REQUEST["data"];  
echo phid;
```

The problem is that it is not echoing the data on the next page, but I can see echo with the full new page in the Firebug response tab of the current page.

Comment: what if you wrap `data` in "? `$.post(myurl,{"data":myVar},function(){});`

Comment: Also you don't have to provide a success function if you're not using it `function(){}` it's an optional parameter indicated by the `[ ]` brackets in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this, so using a form to send data to your page, and you can have more verbose the anchor element:

HTML:

```
<form id="myform" action="../main/patient_history.php" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="data" id="data" />
</form> 


<a data-idref="37" class="see-history" href="#">View Histroy</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

   $('.see-history').bind('click', function(event) {
      try { 
         window.open('about:blank', 'mynewwindow');   
         $('#myform').find('#data').val($(this).data('idref'));
         $('#myform').attr('target', 'mynewwindow').submit();
      } catch(e) {}

      return false;

   });

});
```

**Edit**

if you need to open a new window for each story, you can create a new window with the name of the element id:

```
   $('.see-history').bind('click', function(event) {
      var id = $(this).data('idref');  
      try { 
         window.open('about:blank', 'mynewwindow_' + id);   
         $('#myform').find('#data').val(id);
         $('#myform').attr('target', 'mynewwindow_' + id).submit();
      } catch(e) {}

      return false;

   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead. For your JavaScript `onclick` handler:

```
function phistory(myVar) {  
    var myurl = '../main/patient_history.php?data='+myVar;
    window.open(myurl);                
}
```

Then, in your PHP file:

```
$phid = $_REQUEST["data"];  
echo $phid;
```

Your problem is that you are misunderstanding the use of jQuery's `.post()` method. It simply retrieves the page (with the specified POST parameters) - it does not modify the page such that when you open it in a new window, it will have your specified ID parameter. I switched it so that it no longer uses jQuery's `.post()`, but simply uses the GET parameters by opening the new window with `?data=[YOUR-ID]`. The PHP, you'll notice, stays mostly the same, but I changed the echo statement to include the `$` sign before the variable name. That might have been a typo just in the question, but if that's in your code, it's part of the problem.

Another possibility is to remove the ID from the query string completely, and instead store it as a global variable on the first page, then retrieve that with the `window.opener` property on the second page, like so:

**First page:**

```
var pid=0;
function phistory(myVar) {  
    pid=myVar;
    window.open("../main/patient_history.php");                
}
```

**Second page (JavaScript):**

```
pid=window.opener["pid"];
alert(pid); //Just to check that it's working
```

Comment: but dude i can't use query in this way because by manually changing value in url some other patients histroy can be viewed which is not secure.

Comment: Sorry dont know about it.how can that be done? and is it secure enough?

Comment: @kaushil Seriously are you writing a program for medical patient history? Or is it just a demo. Any

Comment: Only way to make it secure is use ssl, login and sessions

Comment: @Tosh - well said. It is almost as easy to spoof a POST as a GET, and even sessions can be hijacked. With data this sensitive, SSL is in order.

Comment: Also, if you're going to have sessions anyway, the patient ID is best stored as a session variable.

Comment: thanx @D. Strout, ya it was a typo mistake in Q, but what about now secure soltions so no 1 can alter url?

Comment: SSL and PHP sessions. If you don't know how to implement those, you need to learn. Otherwise, you don't really have any security.

Comment: guys the scene is i am having list of patients and onclick on any of them i want to open their histroy on new window.I tried to use my above code and store it in session, but while echoing session variable is not priniting any value.

Comment: @D. Strout i m working on a project so it is serious work, is their any other alternative to send data to newly opened window??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16445/discussion-between-d-strout-and-kaushil-rambhia)

Comment: D. Strout give you a good advice. For security you need add some checks of user's permissions for the requested id in PHP. Or if you don't have user accounts on your site, generate a more complex id.